# MVC3 razor syntax passing a parameter from a link to reset variable inside if statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, variables, razor

Forgive me if this seems like a simple task, I'm fairly new to this...

I'd like to create logic that allows the user to display or not display their email address when editing it from a dialog box. I am placing the link that will allow the user to 'opt out' inside the dialog box - and I'm trying to use the link to reset the variable inside the 'if' statement to 'false' The 'if' statement prevents the email address from being rendered.

Here is my if statement:

```
<div id="change-email" class="text"> 
    @{

        var showEmail = true;

        if (showEmail == true)
        {
            <text><p><span class="label">My email address: </span>@Model.Email</p></text>
        }
        else (showEmail == false)
        {
            <text><p>No email displayed</p></text>
        }

    }
</div><!--#change-email-->
```

And here is the dialog box code:

```
<div id="dialog-email" class="modal">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeEmail", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <fieldset>
           // form code here
        </fieldset>
    }

    <p><a href="" class="no-display">Do not display my email address.</a></p>

</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks!

Comment: Is this all in the same page?  I think you are treating the C# like it runs on the client and you want the link to interact with the C# code.  This would require a round trip to the server (either via ajax or 'standard' request/response).  You would (probably) be better off using JavaScript.

Comment: Yes - this is on the same page. I was wondering if there was a way to have the link interact with the C#. Forgive my ignorance - I just started using #C :P Javascript may be the better way to go... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this with jQuery, and you were okay with the email address still being available in the page source, it would look like this:

```
<div id="change-email" class="text"> 
    <p><span class="label">My email address: </span>@Model.Email</p>
</div>
<div id="dialog-email" class="modal">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeEmail", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <fieldset>
           // form code here
        </fieldset>
    }

    <p><a href="" class="no-display">Do not display my email address.</a></p>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.no-display').click(function(){
         $('#change-email p').text('No email displayed.');
    });
});
</script>
```

It would be a bit more involved if you wanted to persist the preference to not display email. You would probably want to add "Do not display my email address" as a check-box in the *ChangeEmail* form, adjust the Controller Action to which the form posts to handle the preference, and return it as a variable in the ViewBag of the View that the Action returns.

Comment: Nice... I'm going to try this now! I thought about the JQ solution, but I think your approach with the form and controller action may be what I'm looking for.